# handle print dialog in puppeteer headful mode

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Can I control the print dialog in puppeteer headful mode?
In selenium, the print dialog is divided into a separate window handle, so I can control the print dialog by switching with that handle.
However, in puppeteer I cannot control the print dialog. cant't access it.

In the link below, it seems to process the print dialog using windows api. Is there any way to control it inside the puppeteer?

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401867/puppeteer-press-enter-on-print-dialog-screen-has-no-effect)